# Sails js :: Testing variables passed to views

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mocha.js

#### controller

```
module.exports = {

  index: function (req, res) {
    res.view({message: 'hello'});
  }
}
```

How to test if the variable `message` is been set correctly?

```
var request = require('supertest');

describe('HomeController', function() {
  describe('index', function() {
    it('should return success', function (done) {
      request(sails.hooks.http.app)
        .get('/')
        .expect(200).end(function (err, res) {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.body.should.have.property('message');
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

`res.body` returns {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing that the response body has a *property* of `message`, but that's not how view locals work: they are passed to the view as *variables* that the view engine can replace.  If the variable isn't present in your view, the replacement won't happen.  Furthermore, using the `get` method in supertest won't return you a `res.body` by default; you'll need to check `res.text` instead.  So:

1. Make sure your `home/index.ejs` view actually contains `<%= message %>` somewhere.
2. Change your test to something like `assert(res.text.match(/hello/))` to check for the presence of the "hello" string that should replace `<%= message %>`  in the rendered view.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters that are passed to your view function don't look right to me. It looks like you are trying to return a JSON object. Try using the json function instead:

```
res.json({message: 'hello'});
```

If you would like to pass this object to a view file in your application, you need to specify the path to your view file in the function's first parameter:

```
res.view("viewfile", {message: 'hello});
```

Comment: But the code
`index: function (req, res) {
    res.view({message: 'hello'});
  }`
works fine in the browser, as by default the view filename is the method name

Comment: @Muntasim correct: by leaving out the first argument, the `home/index.ejs` view will be rendered.